# What does jQuery's $.each with three arguments do, and how can I translate it to pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove JQuery from a project I inherited and I have stumbled upon this line of code which doesn't really make sense.

```
$.each(options.reservationOptions,this._addToSelect, [select]);
```

What does `$.each()` do when there are 3 things passed to it.
The first is an object, the second is a function, and the third is a var.

Here is the `[select]` init:

```
var select = L.DomUtil.create('select', 'booking-select ' + options.RoomName, reservationContainer);
```

Here is the function:

```
_addToSelect: function (select) {
    try {
        var value = this.value;
        var text = this.text;
        if (text) {
            var option = $("<option>").addClass('booking-option').text(text);
            //var option = L.DomUtil.create('option', 'booking-option');
            //option.innerText = text;
            if ( value )
                option.val(value);
            //option.value = value;
            option.appendTo(select);
            //select.appendChild(option.get());

            //var optionsList = select.options || select;
            //optionsList.add(option.get());
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log('could not add option to select ' + ex.message);
    }
```

Comment: if it's inherited, which version of jQuery did this code target?

Comment: @Mike it is using version 2.1.0

Comment: 3rd parameter should do nothing...

Comment: I believe it used to be extra parameters, but has been deprecated: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L270

Comment: Yeah, in version 1.x it was extra `args`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.x-master/src/core.js#L305

Comment: @schumacherj it might now, but that's not the version that was in use before you inherited, was it?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I have no idea. The code is horrendous and I'm just trying to organize it and cleanup all the extra dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It iterates, the first argument is the array or object, the second is the callback, and the third is the arguments passed in to the callback. In a loop you'd do the same thing with (assuming array)

```
options.reservationOptions.forEach(function(item) {

    this._addToSelect.apply(item, [select]);

}.bind(this));
```

Here's a short version of what jQuery does

```
$.each = function (obj, callback, args) {
    var value, 
        i       = 0,
        length  = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike(obj);

    if (args) {
        if (isArray) {
            for (; i < length; i++) {
                value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (i in obj) {
                value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not according to https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L270, which suggests it does nothing at all with the third argument.

Comment: According to the source, it does do something with the `args` argument

Comment: not in 2.x (see the github link). CurrentjQuery does not do any argument passthrough.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It still does use `args` as of [2.1.3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.3/src/core.js#L292) (latest tag). The `master` branch currently points to [work going towards jQuery 3.x](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/package.json#L5), which apparently removed the argument.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - thanks, was trying to find that, I was looking at the source directly, and even pasted some of it in here, and it sure was present there

Comment: nice. Worth linking to the older code in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**forEach** takes 2 arguments, callback and context – https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach

```
options.reservationOptions.forEach(function(option) {
    this.options.reservationOptions(option);
}, this);
```